# Why my "z" key switches with "y"?

Tags: modeling, axis

So I was modelling and suddenly when I pressed "z" it meant "y" and started grabbing the vertex in the y axis. Also in text editor it typed y instead of z.

When I typed z in notes it typed as expected.

It keeps doing it still, it just suddenly swaps random and stays until I quit and go back.

I use 2.79 on Windows 7

Comment: Mayby you just keep pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, not knowing about it.

Comment: is this only in blender? have there been system or hardware changes? it is likely to do with your hardware or some system issue and not with blender, but you should begin with running blender with factory settings to disable any addons and own user prefs also.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 the hotkey CTRL+SHIFT switches the keyboard layout when you have more than one keyboard language installed. Left Alt + Shift keys switches languages. With an american keyboard language you have a qwerty keyboard layout. With an european language you have a qwertz keyboard layout. Y and Z are reversed.

One possible solution is to remove the second language at Windows 7. No second language, no language switching with the hotkeys anymore. The other possible solution is to disable the hotkeys. For that see for example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926336/how-to-disable-shiftalt-keyboard-shortcut-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

This *may possibly* be that you actually have local transform enabled for the object you are trying to move. If you have rotated the object around 90 degrees, it would appear that pressing the <kbd>Y</kbd> key would be moving the object in the Z axis because of moving the object locally. If you don't want this, then simply disable local transform in the viewport.